# PHPExcel gives error when the script runs as cron

Tags: php, cron, phpexcel

I have created a script to generated excel sheet then attaching it to the mail. It works fine when I run it manually using browser. When I set it as cron it starts giving me an error.

PHP Warning:

```
fopen(uploads/2016_07_29_18_36_42.xls): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/docomo-live/application/libraries/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/OLE/PPS/Root.php on line 90
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Can't open uploads/2016_07_29_18_36_42.xls. It may be in use or protected.' in /var/www/html/docomo-live/application/libraries/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/OLE/PPS/Root.php:93
Stack trace:

#0 /var/www/html/docomo-live/application/libraries/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php(233): PHPExcel_Shared_OLE_PPS_Root->save('uploads/2016_07...')
#1 /var/www/html/docomo-live/Cron_to_positive_cases.php(100): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5->save('uploads/2016_07...')
#2 /var/www/html/docomo-live/Cron_to_positive_cases.php(167): getPositiveData(Array)
#3 {main}


 thrown in /var/www/html/docomo-live/application/libraries/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/OLE/PPS/Root.php on line 93
```

I have tried so much but not able to solve it

below is my code

```
<?php

/******************** Database details ***********************************/
    $dbHost ='****************';
    $userName = '***************';
    $userPassword = '*********';
    $dbName = '*************';
/*************************************************************************/
set_time_limit(0);

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$conn= mysql_connect($dbHost,$userName,$userPassword);
mysql_select_db($dbName,$conn);

if($conn)
{
    echo "connection successful";
}
else
{
    echo "connection unsuccessful";
}

include('application/libraries/Classes/PHPExcel.php');


function getPositiveData($id)
{

    $headings = array('DATE','TIME','CAF NO','CUSTOMER NAME','DEL NO','DEALER NAME','CLUSTER','DEALER CODE');   
    $fileName=NULL;
    $fileName= date("Y_m_d_H_i_s").".xls";
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel(); 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('AV Positive Cases'); 

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter('A1:H1');

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(20);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(20);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(20);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(20);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(20);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(20);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(20);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('H')->setWidth(20);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                ->getStyle('C')
                ->getNumberFormat()
                ->setFormatCode(
                    PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER
                );

    $rowNumber = 1; 
    $col = 'A'; 
    /*********************** Add Headings into the excel *****************************/
    foreach($headings as $heading)
    {   
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$heading); 
       $col++; 
    } 
    $i = 2; 

    foreach($id as $key=>$value)
    {

        if($value['wl_id']!="")
        {
            $sql=mysql_query("select caf_no,concat(cust_first_name,' ',cust_last_name) as cust_name,'' as del_number,dealer_description as dealer_name,location_id as cluster,dealer_code from wl_task_details where wl_id='".$value['wl_id']."'");
        }
        elseif($value['fresh_id']!="")
        {
            $sql=mysql_query("select caf_no,cust_name,del_number,dealer_name,cluster,dealer_code from fresh_task_details where fresh_id='".$value['fresh_id']."'");
        } 
        /************************* Add Data into excel ***********************************/
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
              $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$i, date('Y-m-d',strtotime($value['pos_timestamp'])))
                                            ->setCellValue('B'.$i, date('h:i:s',strtotime($value['pos_timestamp'])))
                                            ->setCellValue('C'.$i, $row['caf_no'])
                                            ->setCellValue('D'.$i, $row['cust_name'])
                                            ->setCellValue('E'.$i, $row['del_number'])
                                            ->setCellValue('F'.$i, $row['dealer_name'])
                                            ->setCellValue('G'.$i, $row['cluster'])
                                            ->setCellValue('H'.$i, $row['dealer_code']);

        }
        $i++;
    }

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('A2'); 
    // Save as an Excel BIFF (xls) file 
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $path= "uploads/".$fileName;
    //chmod($path,0755);
    $objWriter->save($path);

    $subject = "FTD Positive Cases ";   

    $msgBody= "Hi,";

    $msgBody = $msgBody.'<br/><br/>Regards,<br/>Verification Team';
    $msgBody = $msgBody.'<br/><br/>Please login into your SmartAV account by using the following link ';
    $msgBody = $msgBody.'<br/><br/><a href="www.universalmanagement.co.in">www.universalmanagement.co.in</a>';

    $from = '*********';
    $to = '*************';

    $headers .= "From: $from \r\n"."Reply-To: $to \r\n";  

    $headers .= 'Cc: ***********';
    $random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));

    $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";

    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($path))); // Set your file path here



    //define the body of the message.

    $message = "--PHP-mixed-$random_hash\r\n"."Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-$random_hash\"\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "--PHP-alt-$random_hash\r\n"."Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";

    //Insert the html message.
    $message .= $msgBody;
    $message .="\r\n\r\n--PHP-alt-$random_hash--\r\n\r\n";

    //include attachment
    $message .= "--PHP-mixed-$random_hash\r\n"."Content-Type: application/zip; name=\"{$fileName}\"\r\n"."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"."Content-Disposition: attachment\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= $attachment;
    $message .= "/r/n--PHP-mixed-$random_hash--";

    //send the email
    $mail = mail( $to, $subject , $message, $headers );
    if($mail)
    {
        echo "<br />Mail sent";
       $query = mysql_query("insert into cron_status (date_time,status) values (now(),'1')");

    }
    else
    {
        echo "<br /> Mail not sent";
        $query = mysql_query("insert into cron_status (date_time,status) values (now(),'0')");

    }
}
/**************************** Function Ends *****************************************************/


/******************* Query To get Positive cases ********************************/

$query=mysql_query("select task_id,wl_id,fresh_id,pos_timestamp from task_alloc where pos_timestamp like '%".date('Y-m-d')."%'") or die(mysql_error());
$task_id=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    array_push($task_id,$row);
}
getPositiveData($task_id);
/********************************************************************************/
?>
```

Comment: Try run it as a root and see what happen.
It might be permission issue.

Comment: i also have tried with root permission but still it is giving me same error

Comment: root@sys:/home/ubuntu# php -f /var/www/html/docomo-live/Cron_to_positive_cases.php

Comment: OK  in the place you opening file try something like this.
`__DIR__ . /uploads/2016_07_29_18_36_42.xls`
This will generate full path to the file.

Comment: Can you share your cron task? Did you used `wget -o fileURI` as a command?

Comment: The Problem is solved I have used chmod() function to assign permission at run time and it worked for me. Thanks for your suggestions guys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)